# Python 3 - If statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I input look I get the "nothing" printed to the screen.

```
if input("What do you do?") == 'look':
    print("You see a room of equal length and width, You see foreign symbols on the wall.")

else:
    print("nothing")
input()
```

I haven't really been used to python 3 yet but what may the problem here be?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://pastebin.com/rjkLLZjY)

Comment: 1. Check your indentation - Python is whitespace sensitive. 2) Please post the output from IDLE/command prompt/terminal.

Comment: I fixed your indentation, but maybe I shouldn't have, because mixing tabs and spaces could be the problem

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Bad whitespace I am betting.

Comment: There is a newline at the end of the string returned from `input` which you are not expecting.

Comment: @Gabe Not in Python 3. It's stripped there.

Comment: Works with Python 3 here. Not with 2.7.3, of course, unless I type the quotes.

Comment: @DanielFischer: There's a good chance the OP is not using Python 3. Perhaps he is running the wrong interpreter, or maybe he just has the question tagged wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
if input("What do you do? ").strip().lower() == 'look':
    print("You see a room of equal length and "
          "width, You see foreign symbols on the wall.")
else:
    print("nothing")
```

This works fine for me.  Why do you have the final input()?

Comment: Thanks Hal, the code now works. What does the strip function do?

Comment: remove extraneous whitespace at either end of the string.